# Apple News Remove Topic

Tags: big-sur, apple-news

I currently subscribed to Apple One and I'm on macOS 11.0.1.  I never used Apple News prior to subscribing so this is my first experience with it and trying to tune it to the stories that interest me.

The sidebar contains a section titled 'Apple News' and it contains several topics, screenshot below).  I'm not able to customize this section (I can customize sections like 'Following' and 'Suggested by Siri').  I have zero interest in the topic named 'Racial Justice' and want to remove it.

I went thru Preferences and can't find any way to delete that topic.  I know I can right-click on stories and block channels as well as 'suggest less like this', but that doesn't impact this section of the sidebar.  Does anyone know of a way or a hack to remove items from this section of the sidebar?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's News editorial team chooses the categories under ‘Apple News’ and these are shown to everyone in your region. These are not customisable per person.

The categories you choose to be interested in go under ‘Following’, which is customisable and can be removed with a secondary click and choosing Unfollow Topic or Block Topic.